# Javascript not working in IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, getelementbyid

The script below works okay in Windows XP IE8, but when I tried in Windows 7 IE10, it does not work.  Please advise.  I need to get the form names and values.  It works if I run it under Compatibility View.  Please advise.

```
function test1()
{
var x = document.getElementById("myForm");
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++)
   {
  alert(x.elements[i].name + " : " + x.elements[i].value);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think there may be prob with document.getElementById("myForm"); check the id using browser debugger.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with this script, we need to know more details(e.g. the markup of the form)

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop on the `elements`, not on the form itself.

Try this out:

```
function test1() {
  var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
  var formElements = form.elements;

  for (var i=0; i < formElements.length; i++) {
    var field = formElements[i];
    alert(field.name + " : " + field.value);
  }
}
```

Also, be sure that your form really has the `myForm` ID, or it won't be found by the script.

Comment: Tried your script, same problem, it also only works on Compatibility View as well. :(

Comment: Script works when I tested it again on basic form, must be somewhere else giving problem... suspect the <DIV> using AJAX is giving something weird

Comment: I can't help without further details. Remember to re-check if the ID is correct, that the javascript runs after the form is on the page, and that you don't have duplicated IDs.